# can we combine two queries returning result as row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Here I want to get the sum of two table values and my table names are `datas` and `abc_datas`. First I fetched the result of `datas` table as follows-

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_sum
         FROM datas
         WHERE user_id = $user_id")->row();
```

Next I fetched the result of `abc_datas` as follows-

```
$query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_sum
         FROM abc_datas
         WHERE user_id = $user_id")->row();
```

Now I want to combine those two queries and return the total by combining both `total_sum`. For example if `total_sum` of first table is `500` and second table is `1000` I want the output to be `1500` but only first query value is fetching out

This is my final query I wrote-

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_sum1
     FROM datas
     WHERE user_id = $user_id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS total_sum2
     FROM abc_datas
     WHERE user_id = $user_id;")->row();
    return $query;
```

I changed my query like this to get the desired output-

```
 $query =$this->db->query("SELECT
 (SELECT SUM(amount) as total_sum1 FROM datas WHERE    user_id=$user_id) + (SELECT SUM(amount) as total_sum2 FROM abc_datas WHERE user_id=$user_id) as total_sum,(SELECT SUM(agent_amount) as total_agent_amount1 FROM datas WHERE    user_id=$user_id) + (SELECT SUM(agent_amount) as total_agent_amount2 FROM abc_datas WHERE user_id=$user_id) as total_agent_amount,(SELECT SUM(profit) as total_profit1 FROM datas WHERE    user_id=$user_id) + (SELECT SUM(profit) as total_profit2 FROM abc_datas WHERE user_id=$user_id) as total_profit
 FROM dual");
 return $query->row();
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @u_mulder here only first query result is fetching out

Comment: Sum values from `$query1`  and `$query2` and output.

Comment: @u_mulder can we use union to combine both sum results in to one

Comment: So try and you will see.

Comment: i had already used union but it didn't workout for me

Comment: @user_777 Show your union query

Comment: @splash58 i wrote my query justnow please have a look

Comment: You can use * in select only for tables with the same structures. While `SELECT  SUM(amount) AS total_sum` in both subquery will work in any case

Comment: @splash58 but its from two tables and to combine both sum values i guess to do like that

Comment: Than somthibg as - get all records and sum them after `SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_sum from (select amount FROM datas
     WHERE user_id = $user_id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT amount
     FROM abc_datas
     WHERE user_id = $user_id;)")->row();`

Comment: i got my result by changing the query,please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_sum
        FROM   (SELECT   amount FROM datas WHERE    `user_id`=$user_id
                   UNION ALL
                SELECT amount FROM abc_datas WHERE    `user_id`=$user_id) s");
   return $query->row();
```